# NSBezierPath draws in the wrong direction

Tags: swift, macos, animation

I'm using the first time `NSBezierPath`, `CAShapeLayer` and `CABasicAnimation` in a macOS application. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/102590/how-to-create-a-complex-loading-animation-in-swift) as a starting point (it's with UIBezierPath).

I thought, I really know how it's working until I faced this strange issue. No matter what I'm doing the animation always fills the container from bottom to the top.

My layer with the animation looks like this:

```
import Cocoa

class ArcLayer: CAShapeLayer {
    var animationDuration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0

    init(fillColor: CGColor = Constants.Colors.DARK_THEME_MAIN_DARK.cgColor, animationDuration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0) {
        super.init()

        self.fillColor = fillColor
        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
        path = arcPathPre.cgPath
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var arcPathPre: NSBezierPath {
        let arcPath = NSBezierPath()
        arcPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 1.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.close()
        return arcPath
    }

    var arcPathStarting: NSBezierPath {
        let arcPath = NSBezierPath()
        arcPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.2 * 171.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 0.2 * 171.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.close()
        return arcPath
    }

    var arcPathLow: NSBezierPath {
        let arcPath = NSBezierPath()
        arcPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.4 * 171.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 0.4 * 171.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.close()
        return arcPath
    }

    var arcPathMid: NSBezierPath {
        let arcPath = NSBezierPath()
        arcPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.6 * 171.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 0.6 * 171.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.close()
        return arcPath
    }

    var arcPathHigh: NSBezierPath {
        let arcPath = NSBezierPath()
        arcPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.8 * 171.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 0.8 * 171.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.close()
        return arcPath
    }

    var arcPathComplete: NSBezierPath {
        let arcPath = NSBezierPath()
        arcPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 171.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 171.0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 171.0, y: 0))
        arcPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        arcPath.close()
        return arcPath
    }

    func animate() {
        let arcAnimationPre: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        arcAnimationPre.fromValue = arcPathPre.cgPath
        arcAnimationPre.toValue = arcPathStarting.cgPath
        arcAnimationPre.beginTime = 0.0
        arcAnimationPre.duration = animationDuration

        let arcAnimationLow: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        arcAnimationLow.fromValue = arcPathStarting.cgPath
        arcAnimationLow.toValue = arcPathLow.cgPath
        arcAnimationLow.beginTime = arcAnimationPre.beginTime + arcAnimationPre.duration
        arcAnimationLow.duration = animationDuration

        let arcAnimationMid: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        arcAnimationMid.fromValue = arcPathLow.cgPath
        arcAnimationMid.toValue = arcPathMid.cgPath
        arcAnimationMid.beginTime = arcAnimationLow.beginTime + arcAnimationLow.duration
        arcAnimationMid.duration = animationDuration

        let arcAnimationHigh: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        arcAnimationHigh.fromValue = arcPathMid.cgPath
        arcAnimationHigh.toValue = arcPathHigh.cgPath
        arcAnimationHigh.beginTime = arcAnimationMid.beginTime + arcAnimationMid.duration
        arcAnimationHigh.duration = animationDuration

        let arcAnimationComplete: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        arcAnimationComplete.fromValue = arcPathHigh.cgPath
        arcAnimationComplete.toValue = arcPathComplete.cgPath
        arcAnimationComplete.beginTime = arcAnimationHigh.beginTime + arcAnimationHigh.duration
        arcAnimationComplete.duration = animationDuration

        let arcAnimationGroup: CAAnimationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        arcAnimationGroup.animations = [arcAnimationPre, arcAnimationLow, arcAnimationMid, arcAnimationHigh, arcAnimationComplete]
        arcAnimationGroup.duration = arcAnimationComplete.beginTime + arcAnimationComplete.duration
        arcAnimationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        arcAnimationGroup.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        add(arcAnimationGroup, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

I call it in this function:

```
func drawArc() {
    let arcLayer = ArcLayer(fillColor: fluidColor.cgColor, animationDuration: 0.75)
    self.layer?.addSublayer(arcLayer)
    arcLayer.animate()
}
```

The view's width and height are exactly 171.0.

**Expected behavior:**
The dark area (fill color) draws from the top to the bottom.

**Current behavior:**
The dark area (fill color) draws from the bottom to the top.
[image: The dark area (fill color) comes from the bottom and goes to the top]

I'm pretty sure that there is just a very logical issue, however, I really can't find it.

I don't think that's the issue, but here is my extension to get a `CGPath` from an NSBezierPath:

```
import Cocoa

extension NSBezierPath {

    public var cgPath: CGPath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        var points = [CGPoint](repeating: .zero, count: 3)
        for i in 0 ..< self.elementCount {
            let type = self.element(at: i, associatedPoints: &points)
            switch type {
            case .moveToBezierPathElement: path.move(to: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y))
            case .lineToBezierPathElement: path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y))
            case .curveToBezierPathElement: path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y), control1: CGPoint(x: points[1].x, y: points[1].y), control2: CGPoint(x: points[2].x, y: points[2].y))
            case .closePathBezierPathElement: path.closeSubpath()
            }
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use the UIBezierPath to create a view layer mask, then simply have a green/gray view as a subview of the background color and use a NSLayoutConstraint that you can animate.  Reduces the number of redraw required and makes full use of the underlying metal for hardware optimized animations.

Comment: @ekscrypto I'm not sure if this would work as I'm developing a macOS app and Cocoa only offers NSBezierPath. I also want to extend the functionality that it also has curved lines later. The solution of Chucky worked fine for me. Anyway thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like it may be a coordinate issue, NS the origin is top left and CG the origin is in the bottom left, perhaps check that?

Comment: Thanks! You were totally correct. I simply had to change the Y-values to top left origin and it worked fine!